ReactJS - Google register not returning id_token?
I am trying to set-up google login and register on a react frontend and DRF backend.
I am able to login and get the access_token but when I look for profile information and email, I can't access the information as there is no id_token in the response.
I read through a lot of answers on stack overflow and scopes seemed to be a common problem. I tried everything I could think of and find in the scopes, but I just don't receive a id_token.
const GLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      const idToken = response.id_token;
      console.log("Google login:", idToken);
      onGoogleSubmit(idToken);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error("Google login error:", error);
    },
    scope: "profile openid email",
  });




I have tried:
scope: ["profile", "openid", "email"]
scope: ["properurl.profile", "openid", "properurl.email"]
etc

What am I doing wrong?
